# Como eu manda uma consulta do banco para uma View no Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent

Tenho um model (tabela)chamada Membro. Quero fazer a contagem de id que existe no banco. Bem consegui fazer com Membro::Count(‘id’). Ele me retorna tudo belezinha os o total de id que eu tenho na tabela. Mais quando vou jogar na view ele da um erro:
Falando que eu estou tentando obter propriedade e nao objeto
Trying to get property of non-object
Como eu faço uma consulta e mando ela para a View?

Erro:
[image: Erro que da quando eu mando a consulta para a view]

Controller

```
 public function create()
{
   
    $membro = new Membro();
    $ficha = $membro->countID();
    $data = array(
        'titulo'        =>  'Lista de membros',
        'localizador'   =>  'Listagem de membro',
        'info'          =>  'Listas de Membros',
        'avatar'        =>  Auth()->user(), 
        'ficha'         =>  $ficha,       
              
    );


    
    return view('dashboard.cadastroMembros.create', $data);
```

Comment: O código do controle?

Comment: Editei o código

Comment: Adiciona o da view. Para achar onde ele não consegue recuperar a informação

Comment: `membro->count()` altere isso no código no seu `controller`.

Comment: esta no model agora deu certo vlw man obg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta fazer:

```
return view('dashboard.cadastroMembros.create', compact('data'));
```

E quando for imprimir na view algo do tipo {{ $data['titulo'] }}